# Using the same table in a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the Microsoft sample database and the questions from SQLZOO.net to learn SQL for my job. I am stuck on the question:

> For every customer with a 'Main Office' in Dallas show AddressLine1 of
>   the 'Main Office' and AddressLine1 of the 'Shipping' address - if
>   there is no shipping address leave it blank. Use one row per customer.

How Do I use the same table?

Comment: Can you share the table's description and/or DDL please?

Comment: Yes, that's a start. But how can you tell who the address belongs to from this table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to alias the table to join onto itself. For example:

```
SELECT T1.Column1, T2.Column2, ... 
FROM Table1 AS T1
JOIN Table1 AS T2
    ON T1.Column1 = T2.Column1
```

Comment: I maybe being stupid but all I can see is that you have used 2 tables

Comment: 1) Write the equivalent query using Linq in Visual studio. 2) Hover over `T1` to get IntelliSense. 3) Note whether the term 'alias' or 'range variable' is shown. 4) Use this term in future :)

Answer (score 1):

I browsed the AdventureWorks schema and I think this is the right approach. It does involve a self-join which is accomplished by bring the same table into the query with a second alias (Person.Address as "oa" and "sa" below.) Since the shipping address join is apparently optional I would say that that is actually the trickier part of the question to get correct.

```
select ...
from
    Person.Address as oa /* office address */
    inner join Sales.CustomerAddress as ca on ca.CustomerID = oa.CustomerID
    left outer join Person.Address as sa /* shipping address*/
        on      ca.CustomerID = oa.CustomerID
            and sa.AddressTypeID = (
                select AddressTypeID
                from Person.AddressType
                where Name = 'Shipping'
            )
    where
        oa.AddressTypeID = (
            select AddressTypeID
            from Person.AddressType
            where Name = 'Main Office'
        ) and oa.City = 'Dallas'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can see the magic of self joints here -
SELECT A1.Attribute1, A2.Attribute2
FROM Table A1,
Table A2 
where A1.Attribute2 = A2.Attribute1

Or 
SELECT A1.Attribute1, A2.Attribute2
FROM Table A1,
Table A2 
where A1.Attribute1 = A2.Attribute2

In second one you will see the matching values for both attributes.